# TouchesBegan: in UIWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiwebview, hittest, touches

Im trying to add gestures in my web view, like Mercury Web Browser. Im trying to use touches to detect if 2 fingers are tapped on screen and disable scrolling of web view. Is this possible by the UIGestureRecognizer anyways? If not, how can i get touches working with UIWebView? Ive tried changing hittest: method and adding a view over the web view. Nothing works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is supported by gesture recognizers. You can add [`UITapGestureRecognizer`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITapGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to your web view and set its `numberOfTouchesRequired` property to 2.